# XAMPP MySQL command line hangs out when Loading a table

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am a beginner with MySQL and Databases. I am trying to import CSV file into the database using THE FOLLOWING QUERY.

`LOAD DATA INFILE 'followers.csv' INTO TABLE users FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`

I have imported my previous table using this query and it worked perfectly. But, when I am trying to install the second table, the command line is not responding. Also, no errors are displayed. The cursor is staying still, I have not found any Ram occupied and also no disk process going on, except constant CPU process(50% of my actual capacity).

I have looked for any previous answers for the solution but I have not found anything regarding LOAD DATA.

My setup: XAMPP 3.2.2, MariaDB 10.1.29.

SQL Schema:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@session.time_zone;

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `ghtorrent` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `ghtorrent` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `ghtorrent` ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ghtorrent`.`users` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `login` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `company` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '',
  `type` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'USR' COMMENT '',
  `fake` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
  `deleted` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
  `long` DECIMAL(11,8) COMMENT '',
  `lat` DECIMAL(10,8) COMMENT '',
  `country_code` CHAR(3) COMMENT '',
  `state` VARCHAR(255) COMMENT '',
  `city` VARCHAR(255) COMMENT '',
  `location` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ghtorrent`.`followers` (
  `follower_id` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`follower_id`, `user_id`)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `follower_fk1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`follower_id`)
    REFERENCES `ghtorrent`.`users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `follower_fk2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `ghtorrent`.`users` (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```